# ASP.NET MVC2 - Return to previous View from a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I return to the "previous" view from an action in the controller ?

I have an action that can be reached from 2 different views.

The action can result in 2 ways:

Success - and then I return to 3rd different view
Failure - and then I want to return to the previous view (one of the 2) - having the same (old) model data with a TempData["Message"] containing the error.

I want to return to the view that posted to this action - How can I achieve this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass previous view name as a parameter to your action.

```
public ActionResult Edit(DataObject model, string prevAction)
{
    if (model.IsValid)
    {
        return View("SomeView");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction(prevAction, new { data = model });
    }
}
```

Comment: But need to build the model again before I return the View("LastViewName",Model ?)

Comment: You can use RedirectToAction ;)

Comment: can't - as this method returns a view (the "success" goes to a new view). I want in case of failure just to return to the previous view, with the previous data....

Comment: I Thought that there is an automatic mechanism to go to the previous page - like when validation fails... Your code should work and solve this issue, I will check it and also look a little more about the validation failure scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a query string variable that holds the location to where you would like to return.

Something like `controller/action?returnUrl=original/route`